# Modifying Deploy.prototxt in GoogLeNet

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I used pre-trained GoogLeNet and then fine tuned it on my dataset for binary classification problem. Validation dataset seems to give the `"loss3/top1"` 98.5%. But when I evaluating the performance on my evaluation dataset it gives me 50% accuracy. Whatever changes I did it train_val.prototxt, I did the same changes in deploy.prototxt and I am not sure what changes should I do in these lines.

```
name: "GoogleNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { shape: { dim:10 dim:3 dim:224 dim:224 } }
}
```

Any suggestions???

Comment: please do not post screen shots of text, but rather copy-paste the text itself, so search engine can index better the questions/answers on this site.

Comment: I am glad you finally managed to resolve this issue you had. During this process you posted several questions here, that now seems to be "off topic" or duplicates of this answer. Please consider some "cleaning up"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to change anything further in your `deploy.prototxt`*, but in the way you feed the data to the net. You **must** transform your evaluation images in the same way you transformed your training/validation images.
See, for example, how [`classifier.py`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/classifier.py#L88) puts the input images through a properly initialized `caffe.io.Transformer` class.

The `"Input"` layer you have in the prototxt is merely a declaration for caffe to allocate memory according to an input blob of shape 10-by-3-by-224-by-224.

---

* of course, you must verify that `train_val.prototxt` and `deploy.prototxt` are **exactly** the same (apart from the input layer(s) and loss layer(s)): that includes making sure layer **names** are identical as caffe uses layer names to assign weights from 'caffemodel' file to the actual parameters it loads. Mismatching names will cause caffe to use random weights for some of the layers.

Comment: I used the script file given here [Link] (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/classify.py) to evaluate the performance on my evaluation images and it exactly transformed the images in the same way as I did it for training and validation. But still the performance doesn't show any improvement. 

Regarding deploy file, I have one more confusion, do I need to change the layer names which I did it in train_val.txt?

Comment: If I am rescaling the images to 256X256, then instead of 224, shouldn't it be 256.

Comment: @AshutoshSingla there is scaling and then there is cropping. to be strict you need to scale to 256 and then crop to 224.

Comment: You **must** change layer names to match those in `train_val.prototxt`: otherwise caffe will not load the trained parameters for these layers. see the run time log for layers that caffe is unable to load parameters for

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. After changing the layers name in deploy.prototxt, accuracy now comes to close 98% for iteration# 1000.