# Difference in the Validation and Evaluation Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am using pre-trained GoogLeNet and then fine tuned it on my dataset for classifying 11 classes. Validation dataset seems to give the "loss3/top1" 86.5%. But when I am evaluating the performance on my evaluation dataset it gives me 77% accuracy. Whatever changes I did it train_val.prototxt, I did the same changes in deploy.prototxt. Is the difference between the validation and evaluation accuracy is normal or I did something wrong?
Any suggestions?

Comment: difference of ~10% is quite big. how many samples do you have in the validation set and how many in the evaluation set? are the labels distributed the same in these sets?

Comment: @Shai The total number of samples in the validation dataset are 4123 and in evaluation is 4118. For each class, I have made sure that validation and evaluation dataset should contain same number of images.

Comment: that's odd. the difference too big to be dismissed as a "sample error", but too small to suggest a cardinal bug...

Comment: @Shai What should I do to solve this issue and What's cardinal bug?
Do you think that there is something wrong in the evaluation procedure?

Comment: is [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37070319/1714410) helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to you get the fair estimation of your trained model on the validation dataset you need to set the `test_itr` and `test_batch_size` in a meaningful manner.

So, `test_itr` should be set to:

```
Val_data / test_batch_Size
```

Where, `Val_data` is the size of your validation dataset and `test_batch_Size` is validation batch size value set in batch_size for the Validation phase.

Comment: My `test_itr` is 40 and `test_batch_size` is 50. According to your formula my setting is wrong.

Comment: Your `test_itr` should be more than 82. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @user2409356 it seems like your testing phases during training do not cover the entire validation set. Try setting `test_iter` to 4123/50 ~= 83 and see what your accuracy is.

Comment: @Shai After changing the test_itr to 100, the accuracy on validation dataset is 85.4%. Changing Test_itr didn't work.

Comment: @user2409356 do not change it to `100`, it should be `83`: you are over counting part of the validation examples.